# How to make up a style in tcbitemize of tcolorbox to get an effect as like "s" option in \makebox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to make up a style in `tcolorbox` to get an effect as like "`s`" option in `\makebox`.
code example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{style like makebox/.style={...}}
\begin{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem[style like makebox] I am a doctor
  \tcbitem I am a doctor
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

I want the above code to get the effect as shown in the attached figure like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how robust this is, but the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{style like makebox/.style={fontupper=\parfillskip0pt}}
\begin{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem[style like makebox]  I am a doctor
  \tcbitem I am a doctor
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Skillmon! It does work! And a further question: if there is "\\'' in the content of \tcbitem, then the first line loses this ability., for example, "some text\\some text". The first "some text" will be flush left. Is there a better way to solve this? And, could you tell me how "fontupper=\parfillskip0pt" works in my example code?

Comment: @lyl Use `\linebreak` instead of `\\ `.

Comment: And how to give "style like makebox/.style" a higher priority. For example, "\tcbitem[halign=center, style like makebox] some text", the later style will be overrided by the former.

Comment: @lyl include a `halign=justify` in the definition.

Comment: @ Skillmon So simple but so effective solution! Thank you!!